# Export bones Blender

Tags: graphics, blender, skeletal-mesh

I have a simple skeletal mesh created with Blender and I'm trying to export it in order to render it in OpenGL.

My question is: **what is the simplest export format to use in order to analyze the mesh (especially the armature/bones) and render it in a C/C++ program?**

I managed (without too many problems) to render the object in the mesh, so this is not a problem. I searched a lot and I tried different formats, but actually I'm facing difficulties with all of them. It would be great to use `.obj` but, according to my researches, it does not support bones.

Thus, what format should I use to (easily) parse bones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to write a custom script to export the mesh in a very easy-to-parse format.

Blender has a Python interpreter and it's quite easy to write a script, especially if you just want to export your mesh and don't have any desire to provide the community a new exporting script.

A nice place where to start is [Blender 3D: Noob to Pro/Python Scripting](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro/Python_Scripting)

Unfortunately Blender API changed a lot from version 2.4x to 2.5 and above, thus that tutorial is no more up to date (even if still may be useful). 
Thus the best place (until the moment I write I didn't find many good tutorials on Blender 2.6x scripting) where to find material is [Blender documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60a_release/).
Besides, it's Python, so everyone can rely on Python's syntax and constructs and the web is full of Python's tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

[The DirextX .X format supports bones.](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/working-with-the-directx-x-file-format-and-animation-in-directx-90-r2079)

I do not know if the Blender exporter supports the bones.

In general people tend to write their own file formats to tightly fit their requirements.